# Do we have a way to get Heat Map functionality for emails within a Journey Builder. Currently, it is only available for emails in Automation Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I want to know if there is a way to do Heat Map Reporting for emails within a journey builder interaction.

If there is no way to do Heat Map Reporting in Journey Builder, what are some alternative solutions to get this data.
Pls advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Journey Builder Send Email Activities are Triggered Sends and heat maps aren't available for Triggered Sends. I'm not exactly sure of the technical reason why. However, you can still review the total number of links that were clicked by following the steps below.

1. Open the Email app
2. Select **Sends** from the Tracking menu
3. Expand **Journey Builder Sends** from the tree in the left panel
4. Select your Journey Name and Version
5. Select Email
6. Click on **Click Activity** tab

Comment: Thanks for this Eliot. Can you pls help me in directing to check heat map for non- Triggered Send emails.

Comment: Same steps as above, but don't select Journey Builder Sends. You will see the heat map on the click overlay link once you have selected Click Activity.

Comment: Thanks Eliot. This helps.

Can you please let me know if there is a way to implement the same in Journey Builder sends ?

Comment: As I explained, there does not appear to be and I'm not sure why. This appears to be a current limitation.

Comment: Thanks Eliot. what are some alternative solutions to get this data. Can this be done using AMPScript ? or any other method.

Comment: Technically you could achieve this by building a CloudPage of the HTML email and then insert divs on the click regions. You would create a DE containing the tracking data using the [Click Data View](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/) in a Query Activity then use AMPscript [RowCount()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/RowCount.html) function to count the number of clicks and insert the number in the click region divs you created. A bit of work, but it's possible.

Comment: No problem, please feel free to mark my answer as accepted for the benefit of others if this answers your question.